# Ajax refresh div is showing old data after refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi there I am looking for some hints to troubleshoot a problem I am having with ajax refresh , The problem is the div shows latest info on load but when it refreshes it is showing older data . The div shows the latest tracks played on air like I say when the page loads it shows the correct tracks but after 10 seconds when it reloads It is showing older tracks .

Here is my code ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tracks").load("json.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#tracks").fadeOut('slow').load("json.php").fadeIn('slow');
    }, 10000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Any help figuring this problem out would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that data returned from `json.php` is different for every 10 seconds ?

Comment: It may not be different every 10 seconds but when it loads it shows most recent and after 10 seconds it shows older data and continues to show older data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by caching of the browser.
You should explicitly turn off caching to avoid this.

In ASP you could/should set:

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Response.Expires = -1
```

See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) for an excellent discussion about this.

Answer (score 3):

I've found disabling ajax caching doesn't work reliably in all browsers. To be sure to get fresh content, you could add some unique data to the query string, for example:

```
function rand() { 
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*99999)+10000);     
}

...

$("#tracks").load("json.php?defeatCache="+rand());
```